# Would adding `--data-string` to a UDP scan change the results?

Tags: nmap, udp

I'm doing UDP scans on some internal servers and want to add a custom token (randomly generated string) to packets as much as possible in order to later filter out my scans from real non-testing traffic.

To attach my token to my `nmap` scans, I'm using `--data-string`

```
sudo nmap $ip -sUV --data-string "my_token"
```

However, UDP services are sometimes quite finicky and may crash from getting unexpected malformed packets. Would attaching my token with `--data-string` change how services respond, or even crash?

Comment: To clarify, I've removed the point on webapps. I'm testing webapps with the token  too, but for this I'm just considering UDP scanning & UDP services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would attaching my token with --data-string change how services respond, or even crash?

Basically you ask if

- a different payload might lead to a different reaction of the service
- especially if the payload is not conforming to the application protocol expected by the service
- and if the service might crash as a result of such broken payload

Of course it does. Some services will simply drop invalid payload (i.e. no response), some badly written services might even crash on broken payload.

Comment: I was thinking the extra data may get stripped by the time it gets to the service or something like that

Comment: @JohnZhau: the data are appended to the payload. The payload is directly send by nmap to the server. There is nothing in between which might strip the payload before it reaches the service.